# Zend_Tool and project autoloading

Tags: zend-framework, autoload, zend-tool

I'm using Zend_Tool in a ZF app, which was originally generated by Zend_Tool.

I can create controllers fine, but when I try to create an action I get a Fatal Error: Class ... not found in ....

I'm using modular directory structure, and each module has a library folder, mapped to the Library subnamespace.

The controller I'm trying to create an action in extends a custom action controller defined in my library folder, ie.

```
Application\Admin\Library\BackendController
```

which maps to application/modules/admin/library/BackendController.php

So I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Admin\Library\BackendController' not found in /path/to/app/.../controllers/AuthenticationController.php
```

How do I configure autoloading for Zend_Tool so it will load my classes correctly?

Answer (score 1):

you look for your home directory where is the zf.ini, in windows is the directory of you username for login on windows.

just add a line like this:

```
basicloader.classes.0 = "BackendController"
```

if basicloader.classes.0 is taken, just put basicloader.classes.1

usually if you use netbeans for coding, the IDE define:

```
basicloader.classes.0 = "NetBeansCommandsProvider"
```